# Find the depth level in parent-child hierarchy

Tags: linq

I've the table structure like below.

```
Id  |ParentId|  Name
--- |--------|-------
1   |NULL    |A
2   |1       |B
3   |2       |C
4   |3       |D
```

A is parent of B, B is parent of C and C is parent of D.

I want to calculate how may parents each record have?
For example B is referring A, C is referring B and D is referring C.

In this case depth level for A is 0, B is 1, C is 2 and D is 3, based on number of parents they have.

I can do this using recursive function, querying each time if the record has any parent. I want to achieve this using linq query in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this without over calculation, multiple requests or temporary sql tables is select all table at once in a `Dictionary` and calculate parent count on C# side.

If it's acceptable for you it could be done using this function and addition class to prevent excessive calculation:

```
public class ParentInfo
{
    public int? ParentId { get; }

    public int? ParentCount { get; set; }

    public ParentInfo(int? parentId)
    {
        ParentId = parentId;
    }
}

private static int GetParentCount(int id, IDictionary<int, ParentInfo> conections)
{
    if (!conections.ContainsKey(id))
        throw new InvalidDataException($"Id = {id} not found in connections");
    var info = conections[id];
    if (info.ParentCount.HasValue) return info.ParentCount.Value;

    var result = 0;
    if (info.ParentId.HasValue) result += 1 + GetParentCount(info.ParentId.Value, conections);
    info.ParentCount = result;
    return result;
}
```

Then you can get result using this code:

```
var conections = table.ToDictionary(r => r.Id, r => new ParentInfo(r.ParentId));
var result = conections.Select(c => new
{
    Id = c.Key,
    ParentCount = GetParentCount(c.Key, conections)
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it's better to change  your table structure and add another field for pattern
[image: Database]
[image: ER]

**Now you can find a deep level by blow code in high performance without recursive function**

```
using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var foundNode = context.Trees.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == 1);
                if (foundNode != null)
                {
                    var deepNode = context.Trees.Where(w => w.Id != foundNode.Id && w.Pattern.StartsWith(foundNode.Pattern)).Select(s => new { s.Pattern.Length, s })
                        .GroupBy(g => g.Length).OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).Select(s => s.Select(sm => sm.s)).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
```